# What is Accepted NTLM SPNs

Tags: sql-server, tcpip, configuration-manager, spn

In SQL Server Configuration Manager on the Advanced tab in TCP/IP Protocol properties box there is an option `Accepted NTLM SPNs`. What is the use of that option and how it can be used?

Comment: Did you already check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-the-database-engine-using-extended-protection?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Answer (score 2):

- Accepted NTLM SPNs

The Accepted NTLM SPNs variable is needed when a server is known by more than one SPN. When a client attempts to connect to the server by using a valid SPN that the server does not know, service binding will fail. To avoid this problem, users can specify several SPNs that represent the server by using Accepted NTLM SPNs. Accepted NTLM SPNs is a series of SPNs separated my semicolons. For example, to allow the SPNs MSSQLSvc/ HostName1.Contoso.com and MSSQLSvc/ HostName2.Contoso.com, type MSSQLSvc/HostName1.Contoso.com;MSSQLSvc/HostName2.Contoso.com in the Accepted NTLM SPNs box. The variable has a maximum length of 2,048 characters. Accepted NTLM SPNs is on the Protocols for MSSQLSERVER Properties (Advanced Tab) in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-the-database-engine-using-extended-protection?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I've already read the documentation. I've server named EC80A5000SQL1 and I want users to be able to connect using name `SQL`, So I made dns record named `SQL` and in `Accepted NTLM spns` I entered `MSSQLSvc/EC80A5000SQL1.mydomain.com;MSSQLSvc/SQL.mydomain.com`  . Now SQL Server service is not starting.

Comment: Have you tried to change SQL instead of MSSQLSvc/EC80A5000SQL1.mydomain.com;MSSQLSvc/SQL.mydomain.com.
Check this out - https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking_and_servers/9781849685887/1/ch01lvl1sec18/using-extended-protection-to-prevent-authentication-relay-attacks